Error Response not showing up on Spring Boot application
I was trying to run the Spring Boot application to add the Ornament and I was trying to test the error using REST API on Insomnia to get the response such as putting wrong validations like string inputs in integer variables but it does not work showing 500 Internal server error occurred. I tried everything I could but so far not been able to fix this issue. Can anyone help me resolve the issue? Thanks
package com.example.demo.controller;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.model.Ornament;
import com.example.demo.services.OrnamentService;

import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@RestController
public class OrnamentController {
    
    @Autowired
    private OrnamentService ornamentService;

    public OrnamentController(OrnamentService ornamentService) {
        this.ornamentService = ornamentService;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/listAllOrnaments")
    public Flux<Ornament> listAllOrnaments() {
        
        Flux<Ornament> randomOrnaments = Flux.fromStream(
                new Random()
                        .ints(10) 
                        .mapToObj(i -> generateRandomOrnament())
        );
        return randomOrnaments;
    }
    
    private Ornament generateRandomOrnament() {
        Random random = new Random();
        
        String name = "Ornament " + random.nextInt(1000);
        double priceMin = ornamentService.getRandomPrice();
        double priceMax = priceMin + random.nextDouble() * 100; 
        double priceMedian = (priceMin + priceMax) / 2;
        
        return new Ornament(name, 0, 0, priceMin, priceMax, priceMedian, "");
    }

    @PostMapping("/addOrnament")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> addOrnament(@Valid @RequestBody Ornament ornament, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            String errorMessage = bindingResult.getFieldErrors().stream()
                    .map(error -> {
                        String fieldName = error.getField();
                        String errorMsg = error.getDefaultMessage(); 
                        if (fieldName.equals("price") && errorMsg.contains("NumberFormatException")) {
                            return "Price should be a number.";
                        }
                        return "Validation error: Field '" + fieldName + "' " + errorMsg;
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
            return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Validation error: " + errorMessage));
        }
        
        return ornamentService.addOrnament(ornament)
                .thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok("Ornament added successfully"))
                .onErrorResume(ex -> Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(ex.getMessage())));
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/error")
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleErrors() {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("An error occurred.");
    }
}

OrnamentController
package com.example.demo.exception;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException;

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    
    @ExceptionHandler(S3ServiceException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleS3ServiceException(S3ServiceException ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(ex.getMessage());
    }
    
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleTypeMismatch(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException ex) {
        String errorMessage;
        switch (ex.getName()) {
            case "weight":
            case "diamondCarat":
            case "priceMin":
            case "priceMax":
            case "priceMedian":
                errorMessage = "Validation error: Field '" + ex.getName() + "' should be a number.";
                break;
            default:
                errorMessage = "Validation error: Field '" + ex.getName() + "' has invalid type.";
        }
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errorMessage);
    }
    
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleException(Exception ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Internal server error occurred.");
    }
}

GlobalExceptionHandler
package com.example.demo.model;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.Max;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Min;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.Data;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Data
public class Ornament {
    
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @Min(0)
    private double weight;
    @Min(0)
    private double diamondCarat;
    @Min(0)
    private double priceMin;
    @Max(10)
    private double priceMax;
    @Min(0)
    private double priceMedian;
    private String currency;
    
    public Ornament(String name, double weight, double diamondCarat, double priceMin, double priceMax, double priceMedian, String currency) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.diamondCarat = diamondCarat;
        this.priceMin = priceMin;
        this.priceMax = priceMax;
        this.priceMedian = priceMedian;
        this.currency = currency;
    }
    
    public Mono<Ornament> toMono() {
        return Mono.just(this);
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
    
    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    
    public double getDiamondCarat() {
        return diamondCarat;
    }
    
    public void setDiamondCarat(double diamondCarat) {
        this.diamondCarat = diamondCarat;
    }
    
    public double getPriceMin() {
        return priceMin;
    }
    
    public void setPriceMin(double priceMin) {
        this.priceMin = priceMin;
    }
    
    public double getPriceMax() {
        return priceMax;
    }
    
    public void setPriceMax(double priceMax) {
        this.priceMax = priceMax;
    }
    
    public double getPriceMedian() {
        return priceMedian;
    }
    
    public void setPriceMedian(double priceMedian) {
        this.priceMedian = priceMedian;
    }
    
    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
    
    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }
}

Ornament
package com.example.demo.services;

import java.util.Random;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.model.Ornament;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Service
public class OrnamentService {
    
    private final Random random = new Random();
    
    public Flux<Ornament> listAllOrnaments() {
        
        return Flux.just(new Ornament("Ornament 1", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ""),
                new Ornament("Ornament 2", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ""),
                new Ornament("Ornament 3", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ""));
    }

    public Mono<Ornament> addOrnament(Ornament ornament) {
        
        return Mono.just(ornament);
    }
    
    public double getRandomPrice() {
        
        return 1 + (100 - 1) * random.nextDouble();
    }
}

OrnamentService
{
    "name": "Ornament 100",
    "weight": "twenty",
    "diamondCarat": 10,
    "priceMin": 20,
    "priceMax": 10,
    "priceMedian": 20,
    "currency": null
}

REST API JSON testing

500 means server error. Have you taken a look into the error logs of your server?

If you intend to relay the validation error from your @ControllerAdvice, try
overriding the implementation of handleMethodArgumentNotValid as shared below. This is working for us since past while we were attempting something similar:
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override 
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
            MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, WebRequest request) {
        String errorMessage;
        switch (ex.getName()) {
            case "weight":
            case "diamondCarat":
            case "priceMin":
            case "priceMax":
            case "priceMedian":
                errorMessage = "Validation error: Field '" + ex.getName() + "' should be a number.";
                break;
            default:
                errorMessage = "Validation error: Field '" + ex.getName() + "' has invalid type.";
        }
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errorMessage);
    }
}


(Production Sample)
A better implementation if I could suggest for sending out the variable name would be to make use of bindingResult's fieldErrors, for example, we perform a  similar check and send out a BAD_REQUEST to our clients with the following piece:
@Override // instead of  @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class), to avoid ambiguity from parent
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
        MethodArgumentNotValidException exception, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, WebRequest request) {
    logException(exception);
    final List<String> exceptionalErrors = exception.getBindingResult()
            .getFieldErrors()
            .stream()
            .map(DefaultMessageSourceResolvable::getDefaultMessage)
            .toList();

    final Map<String, Object> response = Map.of("Current Timestamp", new Date(),
            "Errors", exceptionalErrors);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}

